# Objective-c "in" operator

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have noticed you can use "in" in objective c in xcode.

What does "in" mean? and how can it be used in code? Could not find anything in google since "in" can be used in normal sentences and the results are very vague.

Comment: If you want Google results, try "fast enumeration".

Comment: @B-Man If one of the answers below helped you with your problem be sure to mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: @NSPostWhenIdle thanks i will do that as soon as i get reply below in of the answers :) thanks :) im guessing i press the "checkmark" to the lefT?

Comment: @B-Man That is correct, and no problem I just wanted to point it out because I see you're new here :)

Comment: Thanks :) appreciate all the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you talking about:

```
for (NSObject* object in myArray)
{

}
```

This is a fast enumeration.

Comment: can you use it to check if an object exists in an array?

Comment: There's a method for that: [myArray containsObject:myObject]

Comment: i think i was looking for en enumeration. i want to check that an object exists in an array not if an array contains an object :) but thanks ! :)

Comment: Wait.. What ? Is it not the same thing ?

Comment: iSofTom not really im afraid. the myObject in my case is a local variable in a delegate method that comes from an array outside the delegate method. so i believe it does make a difference, correct me if im wrong.

Comment: @vishy how can i implelement the isKindOfClass to check if object annotation belongs to myArray?
When i do the for (annotation in myArray) {} and then for (annotation in anotherArray) {} it runs the second enumeration on all annotations. not my intention. i saw some sample code with the isKindOfClass implemented, but i have not made different classes for the different annotations, i am trying to use the same viewconroller for all different annotations. :)

Comment: @B-Man What do you want to do exactly ? [myArray containsObject:myObject] checks that the object "myObject" exists in the array "myArray". Isn't what you want ?

Comment: @iSofTom i want to do the following:
for every annotation that comes from arrayOne, initialize annotationViewOne;
for every annotation that comes from arrayTwo, initialize annotationViewTwo;
It is a MKMapView i am annotating with annotations from different arrays each with its own logo.

Answer (score 6):

"in" used in a syntax for [fast enumeration](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocFastEnumeration.html) over obj-c collections

Answer (score 5):

Here is the official Apple documentation [on the "in" operator](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocFastEnumeration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH18-SW1).

Basically, the construct

```
for(SomeClass* anObject in aCollection){
      ....
}
```

goes over all objects in a collection `aCollection`.

Answer (score 2):

The `in` keyword is used for iterating over objects that conform to `NSFastEnumeration`. For example, to iterate over an array:

```
NSArray *a = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @1, @2, @3, nil];

for (NSNumber *n in a) {
  // Do something with n
}
```